# Meteor images outside of public/

Tags: node.js, meteor, meteor-blaze

TLDR: I'd like to have images in /dir/images not /public/images and symlinks do not solve the problem.

It's a long story but for users to edit a site it would greatly simplify my particular use case if I could keep the templates with the images

My project has `posts/`, `posts/images`, `public/images` and several other branches. Posts is actually a github project that gets auto-deployed. Since it's deployed separately it is a real pain to put images in `public/images`.

Is there any way to do this? I've looked at the router to no avail, and tried symlinks, which cause Meteor to fail to start with the error:

```
error: Symlink cycle detected at public/images/posts
```

The reference on the server is not cyclic in the typical filesystem sense, it just links `public/images/posts` to `posts/images`, one way no cycle as far a I can tell. The cycle must be a Meteor thing.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. How can I serve images out of `posts/images` instead of anything under `public/`?

Comment: This is known issue, was fixed in 1.3.2.4, see this [thread](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/6665)